# error when apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt

I'm now using the command `sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server` to make my  Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS server support NFS. But it reports this error:

```
Need to get 559 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1980 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libcap2 amd64 1:2.22-1ubuntu3
  Temporary failure resolving 'cn.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

I tried to `ping cn.archive.ubuntu.com`, this address cannot be accessed. But I don't think this is the reason, because on my other good Ubuntu machine, I was able to use the command `sudo apt-get install smbfs`, and it worked. The `ping cn.archive.ubuntu.com` command also did not work from this machine.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Rather than `ping`, try `host` to make sure that your computer can resolve the address.  If it cannot, you may need to change DNS servers.

Comment: I'm able to `ping` that hostname as well as run the `host` command.

Comment: Though these errors are on a Rasp. Pi system these workarounds should help: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9307/apt-get-installation-doesnt-work-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: @DopeGhoti.Yes, your solution has just solved my problems.It is the  DNS ip setup problems.After I changed it to a right one , problem solved.Thank you.